# `remote_ip` returns the proxy's IP address instead of the client's IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, http-proxy

I am running a Ruby on Rails application behind a proxy. The proxy sets and sends a `X-Forwarded-For` header to the application as expected. Which might look like this:

```
X-Forwarded-For = '1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2'
```

When I call `remote_ip` Rails returns `2.2.2.2`. Same when the application writes log entries, then the request is logged with the IP address `2.2.2.2`.

This behavior is documented in [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb#L123):

> ```
> # In order to find the first address that is (probably) accurate, we
> # take the list of IPs, remove known and trusted proxies, and then take
> # the last address left, which was presumably set by one of those proxies.
> ```

No unexpected or surprising behavior so far.

But the first part of my problem is that the last IP address in that list is the IP of the proxy itself. That means I actually want `remote_ip` to return `1.1.1.1` and not `2.2.2.2`. Because `1.1.1.1` would be the real client's IP address.

The solution Ruby on Rails provides to this requirement is to add `2.2.2.2` to the `TRUSTED_PROXIES` as described in [ActionDispatch::RemoteIp](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/RemoteIp.html). When `2.2.2.2` is added to the trusted proxies, then Rails would remove those trusted proxies from the list of IP addresses in `X-Forwarded-For` and would return the last from the remaining list of IP, and that would be `1.1.1.1`.

But the second part of the problem is that I am using a managed cloud based proxy. And its IP can change at any time, and its IP might be any IP available for EC2 instances on Amazon AWS. Which makes it error-prone to add its IP in the `TRUSTED_PROXIES`, because it might be outdated at anytime. And there is no option to change the behavior of the proxy. I cannot, for example, tell the proxy to not add its own IP to the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can supply IP ranges as TRUSTED_PROXIES using CIDR notation -- and the active Amazon AWS IPs are easily available -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/aws-ip-ranges.html. Might need to update it on occasion -- but I'll bet the list is fairly stable.

Comment: Turns out you can also subscribe to notifications when they change.

Comment: @dbugger I am sorry that I wasn't clear. The proxy is not provided by Amazon AWS. The provider of the proxy only runs its instances on AWS (at least currently). I guess that mean I cannot subscribe to IP changes, because the instances are not running in my account. Using the CIDR notation for all AWS IP ranges might be an option. But that has the downside that clients running on AWS calling my API would be recognized as trusted proxies and would not be returned by `remote_ip` neither.

Comment: Alas. Other option is to monkey patch  GetIp.calculate_ip and bend it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to work around this problem with an additional middleware that I added to my application's middleware stack right before the `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` that extracts the `remote_ip` for the Rails application.

The middleware only manipulates the `X-Forwarded-For` header after checking that the application is actually running behind the proxy, which I can check by the presence of a specific header. And I only swap the last two entries to still have all IP addresses available for debugging reasons and to now check the default behavior too much.

```rb
# in config/initializers/proxy_remote_ip_fix.rb
class ProxyRemoteIpFix
  # There is a special header only set when running behind the proxy. Use this 
  # header to decide when to enable the `X-Forwared-For` rewrite.
  PROXY_IDENTIFING_HEADER = 'HTTP_X_PROXY_WAS_HERE'
  X_FORWARDED_FOR_HEADER  = 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    manipulate_x_forwarded_for_header(env) if behind_proxy?(env)

    @app.call(env)
  end

  private

  # We can assume that the last entry in the list is the IP of the proxy
  # and the second last entry has a high chance to be the client's
  # real IP address.
  #
  # To trick Ruby on Rails to pick the second last IP instead of the last when
  # calling `remote_ip` we simply swap their positions in the list. We do not
  # remove the proxy instance's IP completely to still keep its IP in the header
  # for debugging reasons.
  def manipulate_x_forwarded_for_header(env)
    ips = ips_from_forwarded_for_header(env)
    return unless ips.size > 1

    # swap the last two entries
    ips[-1], ips[-2] = ips[-2], ips[-1]

    env[X_FORWARDED_FOR_HEADER] = ips.join(', ')
  end

  def ips_from_forwarded_for_header(env)
    return [] unless env.key?(X_FORWARDED_FOR_HEADER)

    env[X_FORWARDED_FOR_HEADER].split(',').map(&:strip)
  end

  def behind_proxy?(env)
    env.key?(PROXY_IDENTIFING_HEADER)
  end
end

# ProxyRemoteIpFix must be added before the ActionDispatch::RemoteIp,
# because its behavior changes the way how the ActionDispatch::RemoteIp works.
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(
  ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ProxyRemoteIpFix
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might review [nginx comment](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1316#comment:7) and accompanying discussion.  In particular, Maxim Dounin recommends configuring your nginx reverse proxy to use X-Real-IP (and, in your case, update rails to support that).

In nginx config, use:

```
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But we aren't using nginx.